# Haskell: Qualified name in binding position?

Tags: haskell

I have a file `test.hs` with the following code:

```
Mp1.gcd a =a
```

When I compile it, there is this error:

> "Qualified name in binding position:Mp1.gcd Failed, modules loaded:none"

I use Mp1.gcd because the official API has "gcd".

Is this problem about my naming conventions? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define it without qualifying it at all:

```
gcd a = {- ... -}
```

Then qualify it in your export list:

```
module MyModule (MyModule.gcd) where
```

Alternatively, remove the possibility for conflict altogether by excluding `Prelude`'s `gcd`:

```
import Prelude hiding (gcd)
```